# Regex for certain numbers

Tags: regex

I would like users to enter certain number (not other than those). How to do that with regex.

example:

```
123451,
456721,
783453
```

Users are allowed for above number to put them in regex?

Comment: `^(123451|456721|783453)$` https://regex101.com/r/qA7rE0/1

Comment: This seems like a better time to use an array and then contains/exists in array

Comment: Are you trying to verify a string is in a given list?

Comment: You want to check for literally those 3 numbers?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which language you are using but I doubt using regex would be a satisfying solution to this problem in any of them. You should instead check for inclusion in a set of expected input.

Anyway if you need to use regex, the following would do the trick :

```
^(123451|456721|783453)$
```